# Using Grep Colour to look in a file, and output with a coloured answer in amongst the file contents

Tags: shell-script, grep, colors

I am currently in the process of writing a program in raspberry pi that will allow me to look inside files and have what I entered displayed in colour I think I need to do something to do with `--colour` but I don't know what to do 100%

Here is my current code.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the name of the file to search within"
read file
echo "Enter what you would like to look for"
read search
```

and then I hope for the grep line.
Thanks for any input!

Comment: It's always a good idea to read the [`man` page](https://www.mankier.com/1/grep)

Answer (score 6):

```
grep --colour=always $search $file
```

This should work if these are the names of your variables.